# Using df.mask to cover up certain material

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to figure out if i can use df.mask for certain things for example my dataframe looks like this:

```
          col1                    col2
1     name1(colonel)         name1(colonel)
2     name2(colonel)         name1(colonel)
3     name3(colonel)         name1(colonel)
```

I want to use df.mask to just cover up (colonel) portion and leave the names alone so my resulting dataframe would look like such

```
col1       col2

name1      name1
name2      name2
name3      name3
```

but I cant seem to do that with df.mask at least I cant find a way to do what I want.

Comment: So you want to remove the strings in the parenthesis?

Comment: I want to remove the parenthesis and what is inside of it thats just how it shows up in my dataframe as name1(colonel) and I dont want the (colonel) part

Comment: Are all columns of the data frame of string type? If so, you can use `replace` with `regex` turned on. `df.replace("\\(.*\\)", "", regex=True)`.

Comment: That worked great thanks how can I award you, since it was in the comments not an answer? Also if you could or have time can you explain what everything in their is doing?

Comment: I just made an answer to explain the regex pattern. Hopefully it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need the replace method on the data frame, which can be used in a *regex* mode. Pattern `\\(.*\\)` can be used to match contents enclosed by a pair of parenthesis, which can be replaced with an empty string (to remove it). A little break down of the regex if you are not familiar with it:

- `\\(` matches left parenthesis;
- `.` matches any character;
- `*` is quantifier which means 0 or more;
- `\\)` matches right parenthesis;

Combined together it matches any string enclosed by a pair of parenthesis inclusive:

```
df.replace("\\(.*\\)", "", regex=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your help and explanation!